# Laravel - Schema - MySql - Temp Table "Already Exists"

Tags: mysql, laravel, rabbitmq, message-queue, temp-tables

I am using Laravel 5.4 for a web app, RabbitMQ for a message queue layer, and the Laravel queue worker. I have two related issues:

**Temporary Tables**

I have the following table-creation code in my constructor:

```
Schema::create('tmp_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->temporary();
            $table->integer('id');
            $table->string('alias',     255);
            $table->string('include',   255)->nullable();
            $table->string('exclude',   255)->nullable();
        });
```

Note the use of

```
$table->temporary();
```

When multiple instances of this process run concurrently, I get the following error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'tmp_products' already exists in /var/www/myproject/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:91

At first I thought the table may not be temporary, however I don't see the table in MySQL Workbench, so it's unlikely.

Maybe the multiple processes appear to be sharing connection state (as temp tables are session-specific). 
The code is run as a Laravel `php artisan queue:worker` command, managed by supervisord (with `numprocs=3`), and I can see in htop that there are three processes with unique PIDs, so I don't understand how they could be sharing connection state.

**Queue - Failed Jobs**

What's more interesting is that I run the queue worker with the flag `--tries=0` (i.e. do not *retry* processing messages), so after the above exception is thrown within the `job->handle()` method the message should immediately be transferred to the Laravel `failed_jobs` table, but what I see is an infinite loop of exceptions and the message never leaves the queue.

So I guess my questions are:

1. How can `queue:worker` processes share db-connection state
2. Why does this particular scenario stop messages failing, whereas they *do* fail as expected if I explicitly `throw new Exception();` in my handle() function

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

**EDIT:** I figured out why the failing jobs were not entering the `failed_jobs` table. Setting `--tries=0` to zero appears to make the jobs try forever. Setting it to 1 fixed it.

**UPDATE:** The same error occurs when using raw PDO:

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
$pdo->exec("CREATE TABLE tmp_products (id INT NOT NULL, alias VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, include VARCHAR(255) NULL, exclude VARCHAR(255) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));");
```

Comment: Try to debug (with xdebug or phpdbg) and see what actually goes on, what connection/driver in use. It looks like some misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

ok I figured it out. I totally misunderstood how the Laravel workers operate. In the back of my head I assumed they work like apache - spawning a worker for each job in the background - and destroying each worker when finished. This is not the case. Each worker listens to the queue, waits, and processes jobs serially. It does not recreate a DB session on every job.

Incidentally, this means that the same error can affect a single worker, on the second job that it processes.

So the temp table from my previous job still existed on the next job. Now I just check, if table exists don't recreate.

Thanks